# XAML - control/ viewmodel changes made in OnNavigatedTo are ignored

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I am developing a client - server app in UWP, which acts like a network intercom and is based on Raspberry Pi (Windows IoT). User clicks button connected to RPi, client gets notification and shows notification page. If user answers the call, it navigates to another page with media element, whose source is network media sink created by the server.This is incoming call page code behind, responsibe for navigation:

```
 private void answerCall_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     speaker.Stop();
     speaker.Dispose();
     Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), true);
 }
```

And this is the code behind on page with media element responsible for handling OnNavigatedTo event (ViewModel class is declared in page's static resources):

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    bool properValue = bool.TryParse(e.Parameter.ToString(), out bool isCalling);
    if (!properValue)
         return;

    if (isCalling)
    {
         MainPageViewModel viewModel = (MainPageViewModel)Resources["mainPageViewModel"];
         viewModel.VideoURL = new Uri(@"stsp://" + SettingsManager.Instance.Values["ServerIP"].ToString());
         viewModel.OnPropertyChanged("VideoURL");   
     }
}
```

The problem is that the part with setting VideoURL and firing OnPropertyChanged doesn't work. Media element source is still null and it shows nothing.

**My question is: Is there any way to commit changes in page's ViewModel properties in OnNavigatedTo event handler?**

Comment: What do you mean by "The problem is that the part with setting VideoURL and firing OnPropertyChanged doesn't work. ". Do you see an error message? Is an exception thrown? 

Have you tried to debug your application? What is the value of "isCalling" ?

Comment: Sure I've debugged this piece od code many times. Every instruction in if block is executed. There is no error, I know that it didn't work, because I have nearly the same action executed in ICommand binded to one button and it works well (media element displays video). It seems like ViewModel is override by framework when lanuching the page.

Comment: The setter for `viewModel.VideoURL` should be raising `PropertyChanged` itself. But that's not the bug. One common cause of this type of behavior is that there are actually two instances of the viewmodel, one that you're manipulating and a different one actually bound to the view properties. Changes in the first naturally won't affect the view. **I'd put a breakpoint in the viewmodel constructor and confirm that only one instance is being created.**

Comment: @EdPlunkett thank you for advise. I will check it.